# HTML, CSS works in JSFiddle not locally

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, browser, jsfiddle

When I try to run my HTML, CSS locally the styles aren't proper but the same works as expected in JSFiddle or any online editors.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mfqs51ce/):

[LiveWeave](https://liveweave.com/vwwK72):

This is how they come up in my browser

[Firefox Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ih1Wv.png)

This is my `<head>` tag

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

The console log looks clean too.

Comment: Check for `console errors` is any file not loaded properly.

Comment: @PrakharSingh The console log looks clean. I have edited the question with it.

Comment: @NcXNaV `<head>` tag ain't a problem. I added what I have in JSFiddle to check & it still has that issue.  I have `popper.min.js` only on JSFiddle not on local. The `<head>` tag that I have posted in the question is the actual one I have locally.

Comment: Because I tried to copy all code exactly in JSFiddle, and it shows the same output.

Comment: @NcXNaV are you saying that the output you see locally is the same as JSFiddle?

Comment: @DasaSathyan Yes, output that I see locally is same as JSFiddle.

Comment: @NcXNaV weird :/